# Why does the same H1 position differ slightly on two identical positioning in two different HTML files?

Tags: html, css

I am creating two HTML files, which would have the same H1 as title inside of a div.
Now, they have the same styling, as I check them out in Chrome Dev tools, one of them is positiong with 20 pixels so the right then the other one in the other HTML file.
Can someone explain this to me, please?

Does it matter if I have different elements below the H1's in the different HTML files? Would that make it differ at all?

I'll give the code on CodePen.io for both with styling, offline the difference is visible, I can't tell if it is online. Please check it out.
I am having trouble with the position of ".center-felso" class.

[HTML file 1](https://codepen.io/arskeliss/pen/RwppdeN)   ,   [HTML file 2](https://codepen.io/arskeliss/pen/oNZZVaR)

**HTML and CSS file 1 code:**

```css
/*HTML file 1 CSS code*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Newsreader&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: #ad5805;
  /*#bd7819*/
  font-family: 'Newsreader', serif;
}


/*Szavak linkjenek dekoracioja es szine*/

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #176300;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #176300;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #000a7a;
}


/*felso szovegdoboz*/

.center-felso {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 650px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}


/*felso szovegdoboz szovege*/

h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #41015d;
}


/*Szavak listajanak kulseje*/

.lista {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 650px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.fomenu {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 25px;
}


/*also szovegdoboz*/

.center-also {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 650px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-felso">
  <h1>Szótár Prodzsekt</h1>
  <h1>Kandabula emlékére</h1>
</div>

<div class="fomenu">
  <a href="../index.html">Főmenü</a>
</div>

<div class="lista">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>
        <a href="#">andalog</a>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="fomenu">
  <a href="../index.html">Főmenü</a>
</div>
```

**And the HTML and CSS file 2 code:**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Newsreader&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: #ad5805;
  /*#ad5805*/
  font-family: 'Newsreader', serif;
}


/*felso szovegdoboz*/

.center-felso {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 650px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}


/*also szovegdoboz*/

.center-also {
  width: 100%;
  width: 650px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
}


/*felso szovegdoboz szovege*/

h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #41015d;
}


/*FlexBox*/

.abc {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
}


/*Hivatkozas vagy link szine*/

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #176300;
  transition: color 1s ease;
  /*Added transition instead of animation, works just right*/
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #176300;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #000a7a;
}


/*Elso sor betuhalmaz(flex-wrap)*/

.a {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 132px;
}

.b {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.c {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 82px;
}

.d {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 108px;
}

.e {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.f {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 66px;
}


/*Masodik betuhalmaz(flex-wrap)*/

.g {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 95px;
}

.h {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 84px;
}

.i {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 38px;
}

.j {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 129px;
}

.k {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 55px;
}

.l {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 90px;
}

.m {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 55px;
}

.n {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 105px;
}


/*Harmadik betuhalmaz(flex-wrap)*/

.o {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 108px;
}

.q {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.p {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 77px;
}

.r {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.s {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 92px;
}

.t {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 85px;
}


/*Negyedik betuhalmaz(flex-wrap)*/

.u {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 96px;
}

.v {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 66px;
}

.x {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.y {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 76px;
}

.z {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  font-size: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-felso">
  <h1>Szótár Prodzsekt</h1>
  <h1>Kandabula emlékére</h1>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="abc">
    <div class="a"><a href="a/a.html">A</a></div>
    <div class="b"><a href="b/b.html">B</a></div>
    <div class="c"><a href="c/c.html">C,Cs</a></div>
    <div class="d"><a href="d/d.html">D,Dz,Dzs</a></div>
    <div class="e"><a href="e/e.html">E, É</a></div>
    <div class="f"><a href="f/f.html">F</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="abc">
    <div class="g"><a href="g/g.html">G,Gy</a></div>
    <div class="h"><a href="h/h.html">H</a></div>
    <div class="i"><a href="i/i.html">I, Í</a></div>
    <div class="j"><a href="j/j.html">J</a></div>
    <div class="k"><a href="k/k.html">K</a></div>
    <div class="l"><a href="l/l.html">L,Ly</a></div>
    <div class="m"><a href="m/m.html">M</a></div>
    <div class="n"><a href="n/n.html">N,Ny</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="abc">
    <div class="o"><a href="o/o.html">O,Ó,Ö,Ő</a></div>
    <div class="q"><a href="q/q.html">Q</a></div>
    <div class="p"><a href="p/p.html">P</a></div>
    <div class="r"><a href="r/r.html">R</a></div>
    <div class="s"><a href="s/s.html">S,Sz</a></div>
    <div class="t"><a href="t/t.html">T,Ty</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="abc">
    <div class="u"><a href="u/u.html">U,Ú,Ü,Ű</a></div>
    <div class="v"><a href="v/v.html">V,W</a></div>
    <div class="x"><a href="x/x.html">X</a></div>
    <div class="y"><a href="y/y.html">Y</a></div>
    <div class="z"><a href="z/z.html">Z,Zs</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add a minimal reproduciable code snippet espacially containg the HTMl of both files. With the details you provided there is no way to tell. The question is to broad and missing vital debugging details.

Comment: Reproducable code added with link for external viewing.
Can you open the question again please?

Comment: There's nothing wrong, both headings look the same. You see one of them is pushed a bit by 20px because the content is longer which causes the browser to add a scrollbar, while the other one doesn't have much text so there is no scrollbar added. If you add more text in HTML1 (so a scrollbar is added) or remove most text in HTML2 (so a scrollbar is added) you will see no difference.

Comment: Oh, right. I see what you mean. So, then it will fix itself, when I add more text content to the HTML file, which I intended to do. WHich means, that the problem seems to be solved.